# Getting header information using c#

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to create an outlook add-in in C# which collects header information from new emails in the inbox. Googling it says to use the following code to get the header information for the email.

```
mailitem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F/")
```

However when I use this the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Click the schema address also says the resource is no longer there is there another way of getting this or do I need to use a different language?

For reference I have added the below.

```
private void Quarantine()
    {

        Outlook.MAPIFolder inBox = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)this.Application.
        ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
        (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        Outlook.Items items = (Outlook.Items)inBox.Items;
        Outlook.MailItem MailItem = null;
        items.Restrict("[UnRead] = true");
        var destFolder = inBox.Folders["test"];
        string StrRegex = @"(Final Score - [-][0-9] | Final Score - [2][0 - 1] | Final Score - [0 - 1][0-9])";
        Regex Reg = new Regex(StrRegex);
        foreach (object email in items)
        {
            MailItem = email as Outlook.MailItem;
               String Header= MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F/");
                if (!(Reg.IsMatch(Header)))
                {
                    MailItem.Move(destFolder);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Forgot to add the expected office version is 2019 professional.

Comment: Are you sure the mailItem object is not null? Where does it come from? And this is not a link, it is a DASL property name.

Comment: Added details in question

Comment: Looks like mailitem is null but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`as` operator will return null is the object is not a `MailItem`. Your code never checks for that. You can have objects other than `MailItem` in the Inbox folder, such as `ReportItem`, `MeetingItem`, etc.

Comment: System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=The property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F/" cannot be parsed or has an invalid format.
  Source=BPX Quarrantine
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(String SchemaName) This is the error I now receive. Each loop checks if the item is a mailitem first.

Comment: Fix by removing the / at the end on the schema.

Comment: @cra74ig - "Fix by removing the / at the end on the schema. "  - You should submit this an answer as it does solve the issue.